# CFBundleIdentifier Collision issue iOS

Tags: ios, xcode

I am archiving the build on Xcode-8.3.3, i am getting following issue can anyone tell me that what i am doing here wrong?

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: check your bundle idenifier once

Comment: It seems [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29746941/4294543) nearly unique, &  your dependancy framework identifier issue or same identifier used by another application

Comment: Check whether Applozic  added in both  "Embedded Binaries" and  "Linked framworks and Libraries"? yes then remove it from "Embedded Binaries" and then try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the provisioning profile once & recreate it,You must need to tackle Bundle identifier correctly.

Other possible solutions may be,

[CFBundleIdentifier Collision](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31015978/4294543)

[error itms-90451 "CFBundleIdentifier Collision Error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29608264/error-itms-90451-cfbundleidentifier-collision-error/29746941#29746941)

Comment: I don't know what i did wrong previously but remove all old things & Generate new this trick did works for me.